# Python type error trying to initialize miniconda

Tags: python, installation, conda, typeerror, miniconda

I'm on the last step of installing miniconda (I downloaded the installer and cleaned it up), and I run into this error when running

```bash
~/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

It prompts me for my password and then gives me this error (this is the last line):

```
      File "/Users/angeliquecd/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 2088, in _communicate
        input_view = memoryview(self._input)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

$ /Users/angeliquecd/miniconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtVVo.png)

It also gives me these environment variables:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0yB5.png)

```
             CIO_TEST=<not set>
           CONDA_ROOT=/Users/angeliquecd/miniconda3
       CURL_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
           LD_PRELOAD=<not set>
                 PATH=/Applications/miniconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Vers
                      ions/3.11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/
                      Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Framewor
                      ks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/
                      App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Library
                      /Apple/usr/bin
   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
        SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
```

This makes me think there's an issue with different versions of python being used by the installer and by my system, but I've downloaded the python 3.11 and when I type in `python --version` I get Python 3.11. I also tried with 3.12.

If anyone has advice that would be amazing.

Comment: If you google the error message, you get results that look promising, like this: [Conda Init Error Reads -- TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' - Getting Started - Anaconda Community](https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/conda-init-error-reads-typeerror-memoryview-a-bytes-like-object-is-required-not-str/30786)

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research.